# OSGi Console not showing in Glassfish 3.1.1 admin pages

Tags: console, glassfish, osgi

I just installed a fresh new glassfish 3.1.1 instance. For some reasons, I needed to change the default HTTP port to 9081 and the admin port to 9049.

Then from the admin interface I used the update tool to install the OSGi console.

I now do have a new "OSGi Console" tab in the server admin page, but when I click on it, the contents don't load. As it turns out, the tab is trying to load the page from the standard HTTP port (8080), whereas my configured HTTP port is 9081.

When I try to access the OSGi console directly from another browser with my admin port (http://localhost:9049/osgi/system/console/bundles/), everything's showing up fine, so the installation in itself is ok.

So my question is, how do I setup glassfish so that the request is properly redirected?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

File a bug in osgi category in glassfish jira. The OSGi console plugin should have the intelligence to know which port the server is configured to listen for http requests.